# Restrict selection to single select of a listboxFor- MVC 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, listbox

I am using following code to generate a list box..

```
    <%: Html.ListBoxFor(m => m.Subscribers, new List<SelectListItem>(), new { @class = "list_style_Wizard" })%>
```

But we can select more than one items from the listbox.. How can i restric it to single select ???

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Html.ListBoxFor` is used to render a multiple choice list box. For single choice use
`Html.DropDownListFor`

```
<%: Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Subscribers, listOfsubscribers, new { @class = "list_style_Wizard" }) %>
```

Comment: Often a single select listbox is a better choice than a DropDown. It's too bad that Microsoft chose not to make this optional.

Answer (score 10):

The HTML helpers `DropDownListFor` and `ListBoxFor` seem to add the `multiple` attribute when rendering as a listbox. I use a combination of the `DropDownListFor`/`ListBoxFor` and a jQuery [livequery](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/livequery) selector to remove the `multiple` attribute. In Razor use:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedId, Model.SelectList, 
    new { size = 10, @class = "selectOneListBox" })
```

and in JavaScript:

```
$(".selectOneListBox").livequery(function () {
    $(this).removeAttr('multiple');
});
```

I'm sure you could also write your own version of the HTML helper routine that doesn't spit out the `multiple` attribute.

Comment: Livequery is no longer advisable to be used. So, it is probably better to remove the attribute just when page is loaded:        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".selectOneListBox").removeAttr('multiple');
        });

Comment: Good call Anelook. I love livequery, it makes coding unobtrusive JavaScript simple, especially for dynamically created content. However it does have performance implications. Your suggestion will perform better and may be best for this scenario.

Comment: Only size attribute is enough, no need for jquery code.